# Kernel constantly crashes while compiling my code

Tags: python, data-science, networkx, jupyter-lab, osmnx

I am currently trying to get the drive network of Continental Portugal, which is a Polygon. However kernel on the last line of code crashes. In the ubuntu terminal it says; 'Created graph with 4,901,116 nodes and 9,503,596 edges in 101.64 seconds', seconds later kernel gives me the following message: 'Kernel Restarting The kernel for Desktop/osmnx_project.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically'

```
import geopandas as gpd 
import pandas as pd 
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon 
import networkx as nx 
import osmnx as ox 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from descartes import PolygonPatch 
from IPython.display import IFrame 
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

place = 'Portugal'

G = ox.gdf_from_place(place)

exploded_G = G.explode()

exploded_G['area'] = exploded_G.area
exploded_G.sort_values(by='area', inplace=True)

Portugal= exploded_G.iloc[-1]['geometry']

g = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon = Portugal, network_type = 'drive')
```

Can anyone help me figure out exactly what is wrong or if there is a way to simplify my code in order to be lighter and faster. I suspect it could be a RAM issue, but my computer has 16GB of RAM

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem like a `RAM` issue to me.

Referring to a [similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829#issuecomment-300783730), below is the suggested solution.

> Don't use Jupyter notebook. Use a simple .py script. There are  known problem with notebook. It doesn't allow cuda to deallocate resources once the session is over which creates problems.

Comment: Thank you, I will use spyder instead of jupyter